# Resolving an exception with LoadToolbarEx and difference between count of normal v large images

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar

I just tried running my `CDialog` app in debug and I get an exception. It relates to my creation of myu toolbar.

I call this mention in `OnInitDialog`:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::CreateToolbar()
{
    DWORD dwCtrlStyle = TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
    DWORD dwStyle = AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE;
    if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, dwCtrlStyle,
        dwStyle, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR))
    {
        dwStyle = CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
        m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle() | dwStyle);

        CMFCToolBarInfo info;

        info.m_uiColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiLargeColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiLargeHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;

        m_ToolBar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_TOOLBAR, info, FALSE);

        CSize   sizeToolBar = m_ToolBar.CalcFixedLayout(TRUE, TRUE);
        m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, sizeToolBar.cx, sizeToolBar.cy,
            SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);

        // Move all controls down
        CPoint ptOffset(0, sizeToolBar.cy);

        CRect  rcChild;
        CWnd* pwndChild = GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
        while (pwndChild)
        {
            if (pwndChild->GetSafeHwnd() != m_ToolBar.GetSafeHwnd())
            {
                pwndChild->GetWindowRect(rcChild);
                ScreenToClient(rcChild);
                rcChild.OffsetRect(ptOffset);
                pwndChild->MoveWindow(rcChild, FALSE);
            }
            pwndChild = pwndChild->GetNextWindow();
        }

        // Resize the window
        CRect rcWindow;
        GetWindowRect(rcWindow);
        rcWindow.bottom += sizeToolBar.cy;
        MoveWindow(rcWindow, FALSE);

    }
}
```

The exception is on this line:

```
LoadToolBarEx
```

When I trace the code I end up at this `ASSERT`:

```
// Load large images:
if (params.m_uiLargeHotResID != 0)
{
    if (!m_LargeImages.Load(params.m_uiLargeHotResID, NULL, TRUE))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ASSERT(m_Images.GetCount() == m_LargeImages.GetCount());
}
```

When I view these variables:

- `m_Images` has 10 images.
- `m_LargeImages` has 5 images.

This is the call stack:

```
>   Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CMFCToolBar::LoadBitmapEx(CMFCToolBarInfo & params, int bLocked) Line 781    C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CMFCToolBar::LoadToolBarEx(unsigned int uiToolbarResID, CMFCToolBarInfo & params, int bLocked) Line 872  C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::CreateToolbar() Line 2288  C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::OnInitDialog() Line 246    C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!AfxDlgProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 __formal, __int64 __formal) Line 28 C++
    [External Code] 
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CWnd::DefWindowProcW(unsigned int nMsg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 1100   C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CWnd::Default() Line 299 C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CDialog::HandleInitDialog(unsigned __int64 __formal, __int64 __formal) Line 721  C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam, __int64 * pResult) Line 2441   C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 2099    C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 265  C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 418   C++
    [External Code] 
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!IsolationAwareCreateDialogIndirectParamW(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, const DLGTEMPLATE * lpTemplate, HWND__ * hWndParent, __int64(*)(HWND__ *, unsigned int, unsigned __int64, __int64) lpDialogFunc, __int64 dwInitParam) Line 569 C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CWnd::CreateDlgIndirect(const DLGTEMPLATE * lpDialogTemplate, CWnd * pParentWnd, HINSTANCE__ * hInst) Line 358   C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CWnd::CreateRunDlgIndirect(const DLGTEMPLATE * lpDialogTemplate, CWnd * pParentWnd, HINSTANCE__ * hInst) Line 460    C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CDialog::DoModal() Line 633  C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::InitInstance() Line 251    C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 37  C++
    Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 26    C++
    [External Code]
```

My main PNG toolbar resource has 10 images. Yet I specified this code:

```
info.m_uiColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
info.m_uiHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
info.m_uiLargeColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
info.m_uiLargeHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
```

My toolbar image is 320 x 32.

How do I deal with this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have come across the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbar-class?view=vs-2019#loadtoolbarex).

> ```
> CMFCToolBar::m_dblLargeImageRatio
> ```
>
> Specifies the ratio between the dimension (height or width) of large
>   images and the dimension of regular images.
>
> Remarks The default ratio is 2. You can change this value to make
>   large toolbar images larger or smaller.
>
> The framework uses this data member when you do not specify a set of
>   large images. For example, if you provide only the set of small images
>   with size 16x16 and want the large images to have the size 24x24, set
>   this data member to 1.5.

```
CMFCToolBar::m_dblLargeImageRatio = 1.0;
```